# Should ViewData never be used?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, viewdata

I have tried to check the best practices for using asp.net mvc and quite a few say that we should never use ViewData. I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423148/when-is-it-right-to-use-viewdata-instead-of-viewmodels) and it seems like it from that.

One reason that I can think of using ViewData is if you are looking to pass just one value to the view.But for more than one values it seems that it would better to use ViewModels. But if they are being included as a part of framework then they should have some advantages and benefits.

What are the cases when I should use ViewData ? What are the best practices to be followed when using ViewData so that it is not misused ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to use strongly typed view models from the outset.
I much prefer the lack of "magic strings" by doing this.

Never one rule for *all* situations but this is usually the first approach I take.

Comment: magic strings themselves can be avoided by having constant strings.. just saying..

Answer (score 0):

Quote from Scot Gu (link to source: [nerddinnerbook](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part6.htm))

> Using string-based dictionaries, since
>   typos, can lead to errors that will not
>   be caught at compile-time. The
>   un-typed ViewData dictionary also
>   requires using the "as" operator or
>   casting when using a strongly-typed
>   language like C# in a view template.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of a strongly typed ViewPages in couple with a strongly typed Model or ModelView is a perfect practice of the ASP.NET MVC.

You can use ViewData to transfer additional data to ViewPage but I preffer ViewModels because:

1. Compile time errors vs runtime errors
2. IntellySence support
3. Easy refactoring
4. No magic strings
5. Html helper to construct form with data bindings

Answer (score 0):

I often find myself using ViewData when I need to append data to the current request by way of some base controller or filter. Commonly, master pages will have dynamic content which must be retrieved from the server, and rather than modifying the model returned by the view, or wrapping every model returned in a parent ViewModel, I can simply place the additional data in ViewData.

In order to avoid using strings in my views, I'll often place a const field in a controller class or similar and call the field within the View.

```
public abstract partial class BaseController : Controller
{
    public const string MessagesViewDataKey = "Base.Messages";

    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) {
        if (filterContext != null && filterContext.Controller != null && !filterContext.IsChildAction) {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData[MessagesViewDataKey] = Messenger.MessageQueues;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}

// site.master
<% if (ViewData[BaseController.MessagesViewDataKey] != null)
           Html.RenderPartial("DisplayTemplates/MessageList", ViewData[BaseController.MessagesViewDataKey]); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like using them, but I've found them useful in a situation where I want to display some kind of message to the user on all pages. For example I have a user control that displays messages to the user. It is also present in my master page. It checks `ViewData["messages"]` and `TempData["messages"]` And if one of those is not null it displays the messages that are present. If they are both null it doesn't.

This allows me to keep all of my models from having to inherit from a base class that has a Messages property and gives me more flexibility.